# SQL select filtrar dato solo si todos los registros son similares

Tags: sql, oracle

me gustaría filtrar en sql todos los nombres solo si todos los registros que posee son inactivos

ejemplo de datos

```
Id | nombre | estado
== | ====== | ==========
 1 | pepe   | activo
 2 | pepe   | activo
 3 | pepe   | inactivo
 4 | pepe   | inactivo
 5 | pepe   | inactivo
 6 | pepe   | inactivo
 7 | agusto | inactivo
 8 | agusto | inactivo
 9 | agusto | inactivo
```

Resultado esperando
`agusto`

Lo que he logrado hacer es:

```
select nombre 
from tabla 
group by nombre 
having count(case when estado='inactivo' then 1 else 0 end)<1
```

Pero me trae 0 resultados.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Edite incorporando la query que he logrado hacer.

Comment: no entiendo mucho tu pregunta. ¿Notas que el titulo de lo que quieres resolver es diferente de lo que muestras en el "Resultado esperado" de tu ejemplo?

Comment: Entiendo que negando los nombres que tengan algún estado `activo` debieras resolverlo, por ej: `select distinct nombre from tabla where nombre not in (select distinct nombre from tabla where estado = 'activo')`

Answer (score 2):

Puedes lograrlo utilizando un `not exists` en el `where` para encontrar todos aquellos que no tienen registros activos.

Dado que los nombres se repiten, a la vez, utiliza `distinct` para listar solo una vez cada nombre.

Por ejemplo:

```
select distsinct t1.nombre
  from tabla t1
 where not exists (select 1 
                     from tabla t2 
                    where t2.nombre = t1.nombre 
                      and t2.estado = 'activo')
```

Comment: duda real, que genera en la consulta que hagas esto: `SELECT 1`?

Comment: Si hiciera solo `select 1 from tabla`, me va a devolver una lista de _unos_, tantos como filas tenga la tabla. Suelo utilizarlo en sentencias `exists` y `no exists` para indicar explícitamente que no me interesa ningún dato real de la tabla, solo saber si la consulta devuelve filas o no. Históricamente hubo motores que no eran capaces de optimizar esto y si ponías `select * from tabla`, recuperaban físicamente los datos, para luego solo ver si había alguna fila o no. Utilizar `select 1` garantizaba que se podía obviar este paso, sobre todo si el `where` se puede resolver con indices.

Comment: muchas gracias, lo había visto en otros momentos pero no entendía el por que

Comment: Son mañas que uno va agarrando con los años... jaja. Actualmente muchos motores debieran resolver esto sin problemas, pero yo suelo perder el hilo y hay motores como _mySQL_, _postgreSQL_ y otros que no sé cómo van con esto.

Answer (score 0):

Intentalo de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT nombre 
FROM tabla
GROUP BY nombre
HAVING sum(CASE estado WHEN 'activo' THEN -1000 else 1 end) > 0
```

Comment: Deberías explicar por qué da el resultado esperado. Además, el usar -1000 es un enfoque malísimo para resovler la consulta.

Comment: OJO: Si un nombre aparece activo una vez e inactivo 1001 veces vas a incluirlo en el resultado.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaracion doc, exacto. tiene la debilidad en el numero que señalas. es mejorable si previamente se realiza una consulta para identificar la cantidad maxima de registros con valor inactivo, se coloca en una variable y esta puede servir como parametro en la consulta. Existen por su puesto mejores formas.