# Consulta en 3 tablas con JOIN mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

ando ya dándole vueltas un par de dias a una consulta entre 3 tablas, yo creo que esta consulta ya muchos con experiencia la deben haber formulado en algún momento.

Tengo 3 tablas :

```
 CREATE TABLE printers (  
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,  
  name varchar(255),  
  model varchar(20),  
  ip varchar(20),    
  cod_patri varchar(20),   
  serial_code varchar (50),  
  property int (2) default 0,  
  status int (2)  default 1  
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

 CREATE TABLE areamdi(  
    id int(11) int NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,    
    name varchar(50),  
    croquis_pdf varchar (50),    
    croquis_visio varchar (50),    
    piso int (3) not null,   
    edificio int(3) not null  
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

 CREATE TABLE ext_area (  
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,     
  area_id int (11) not null default 1,   
  printer_id int (11) not null default 1,
  FOREIGN KEY (printer_id) REFERENCES printers(id),     
  FOREIGN KEY (area_id) REFERENCES areamdi(id)   
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Mi problema esta en que yo quiero hacer un select de las impresoras diponibles por Area , supongamos que inserto estos datos:

```
INSERT INTO printers (name, model, serial_code, ip ) value ('SP5200_A001','Ricoh SP5200','S9029600438','10.0.99.230');          /*2*/
INSERT INTO printers (name, model, serial_code, ip ) value ('SP5200_A002','Ricoh SP5200','S9038500133','10.0.120.241');         /*3*/
INSERT INTO printers (name, model, serial_code, ip ) value ('SP5200_A003','Ricoh SP5200','S9038500138','10.0.120.242');         /*4*/
INSERT INTO printers (name, model, serial_code, ip ) value ('SP5200_A004','Ricoh SP5200','S9049601296','10.0.120.246');         /*5*/
INSERT INTO printers (name, model, serial_code, ip ) value ('SP5200_A005','Ricoh SP5200','S9148701028','10.0.120.250');         /*6*/
INSERT INTO printers (name, model, serial_code, ip ) value ('SP5200_A006','Ricoh SP5200','S9038500131','192.168.11.120');       /*7*/
INSERT INTO printers (name, model, serial_code, ip ) value ('SP5200_A007','Ricoh SP5200','S9049300891','192.168.12.50');        /*8*/
INSERT INTO printers (name, model, serial_code, ip ) value ('SP5200_A008','Ricoh SP5200','S9148600679','192.168.10.250');       /*9*/

INSERT INTO areamdi (name, piso, edificio) value  ('LOGISTICA', 2, 3);
INSERT INTO areamdi (name, piso, edificio) value  ('ALMACEN', 1, 3);


insert into ext_area (area_id, printer_id) value (1,1);
insert into ext_area (area_id, printer_id) value (1,2);
insert into ext_area (area_id, printer_id) value (1,3);
insert into ext_area (area_id, printer_id) value (1,4);
insert into ext_area (area_id, printer_id) value (2,1);
insert into ext_area (area_id, printer_id) value (2,2);
insert into ext_area (area_id, printer_id) value (2,3);
insert into ext_area (area_id, printer_id) value (2,4);
```

Aqui yo ya asigne la impresora 1,2,3,4 al area 1(Logistica) y 2(Almacen), bueno lo que yo hago para intentar mostrar las impresoras disponibles para logistica que serian todas menos la 1,2,3 y 4, osea debería mostrar en logística como impresora disponible la 5,6,7,8,9,10 y en almacén de igual manera ya que a ambas les asigne las mismas impresoras estás 2 áreas comparten impresoras en caso tenga una nueva área debería poder ver las 10 impresoras ya que para una nueva área están disponibles todas las impresoras.

```
SELECT 
printers.id as id_printer, printers.name as name_printer, model as model_printer, ip as ip_printer
FROM printers 
LEFT JOIN ext_area ON printers.id = ext_area.printer_id
LEFT JOIN areamdi ON areamdi.id = ext_area.area_id 
WHERE areamdi.id!=1 /* codigo del area que le paso por PHP*/

UNION

SELECT
printers.id as id_printer, printers.name as name_printer, model as model_printer, ip as ip_printer
FROM printers 
LEFT JOIN ext_area ON printers.id = ext_area.printer_id
LEFT JOIN areamdi ON areamdi.id = ext_area.area_id 
WHERE areamdi.name is null and printers.id>1
```

En un momento pense que lo habia conseguido pero al final no me cuadro, supuestamente me mostraba todas las impresoras disponibles, pero luego me di cuenta que al hacer mas registros de las mismas impresoras pero en otras  areas estas se inlcuyen en el select tambien y vuelven a aparecer en mis disponibles y entiendo que es porque se vuelven registros en ext_area y los estoy listando nuevamente.... que solucion podria darle?? alguien me podria ayudar porfavor..

Comment: No comprendo, dices que esperas obtener todas las impresoras, menos la 1 y la 2, pero en el insert, asocias a esa área la 1, 2, 3 y 4, por lo que una consulta correcta debiera devolverte estas mismas impresoras.

Comment: @jachguate, hola gracias por tu atencion. Si mira osea yo inserte las impresoras 1,2,3 y 4 a las areas 1 y  2 por separado es decir es cada area es independendiente de sus impresoras por esos mis tablas n:n , ahora lo que yo quiero es cuando consulte en el area 1 o  area  2 me muestren solo las disponibles que en esta caso seria todas las impresoras no asignadas pero por area. cuando yo ejecuto mi consulta y conforme voy agregando impresoras a otras areas , la consulta mal elaborada de mi parte , empieza a mostrarme impresoras de otras areas.. que yo en mi area ya tengo asignada..

Comment: ¿No estarías buscando en realidad, las impresoras "exclusivas" de cada area? es decir las que solo son del área y no están compartidas

Comment: En otras palabras, ¿las impresoras "disponibles", son las que no han sido asignadas a un área en particular?. Creo que hace falta definir bien que significa entonces una "impresora disponible".  Lo que yo había entendido es que una impresora "disponible" para un área, es aquella impresora que SI ha sido asignada a dicha área.

Comment: @Patricio, en ese caso, en el ejemplo, la respuesta estaría vacía, pues no hay ninguna impresora "exclusiva" de esa área. Las 1, 2, 3 y 4 están todas asignadas a las dos áreas. No me aclaro, la verdad.

Comment: @jachguate, si, lo veo, pero cabe la posibilidad que el [mcve] este mal. Sino no veo por que el resultado sería la 1 y 2 cuando las 4 están asignadas a cada área

Comment: Disculpen si no me explique bien , osea yo trabajo en una empresa y esta empresa tiene 10 impresoras , ahora estas impresoras son asignadas a diferentes áreas , ahora algunas están en más de un área , cuando yo desde mi aplicación seleccionó un área y luego con un botón le doy asignar impresora me muestra las 10 impresoras , lo que yo quiero es que me muestre las impresoras disponibles en el caso  que ya tengo asignada 1 , me deberían mostrar las 9 restantes y así por cada área que yo seleccione .

Comment: Lo que en mi consulta me funciona pero con 1 área , le asignó 5 y me muestra las 5 disponibles que aún no han sido asignadas en mi 'area'  , pero cuando voy a otra área y me muestra las 10 disponibles todo ok, porque esa área no tiene. Ninguna impresora asignada , entonces le asignó 1 o más impresoras , aquí el problema porque las asigna pero en el área anterior dónde me mostraba las 5 disponibles ahora me muestra también las impresoras que le asigne a esta última área . Gracias por sus respuestas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes valerte de la expresión `not exists`, para obtener solamente aquellas impresoras que no han sido asignadas a un área en particular.

Por ejemplo, para obtener las impresoras que no han sido asignadas a Logística, puedes hacer:

```
select printers.id, printers.name, printers.model, printers.ip
  from printers 
 where not exists (select 1
                     from ext_area 
                    where ext_area.printer_id = printers.id
                      and ext_area.area_id = 1 /* el id de logística */
                  )
```

En lenguaje natural esto sonaría algo como:

Seleccionar todas las impresoras para las que no existe una asignación de impresora en el departamento logística.

Comment: funciono. Muchas gracias ! yo soy nuevo en esto , mira tengo una duda en el segundo select  que significa este "1" , porque  e estado probando y poniendo otros numeros y no afecta a la consulta ,almenos no a primera vista. Gracias

Comment: Lee mis comentarios a [esta otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/271307/21), creo que eso te sacará de la duda. Un saludo.